# Is an incremental state update a feasible approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, jsx

I wrote a framework called React Server, that mimics React on the serverside. It features a few familiar concepts from React, like components, states, hooks, effects but on the serverside.

A serverside component looks the following

```js
export const HelloWorldExample2 = () => {
  // The useState hook looks familiar?
  const [count, setState] = useState(0, {
    key: "count",
    scope: Scopes.Global,
  });

  // A simple function that can be executed from the client side.
  const increase = () => {
    setState(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    // Simply pass down props to the client side.
    <ServerSideProps
      key="hello-world-2-props"
      count={count}
      increase={increase}
    />
  );
};
```

<sup>See https://state-less.cloud for more information</sup>

The concept is similar to react on the frontend. You have a `useState` hook and calling the setter re-renders the component on the server. Components that are rendered on the server can be consumed by a clientside hook `useComponent` which receives all the props passed from the server side. If a component re-renders on the server, all connected clients receive the updated state.

Now suppose you have a modestly complex server-side application, illustrated in the below code.

```js
const Item = (props) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(props);
  const toggle = () => {
    setItem({
      ...item,
      completed: !item.completed,
    });
  };

  return <ServerSideProps toggle={toggle} {...item} />;
};

const List = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const createItem = () => {
    const newItem = {
      id: uuid(),
      title: "New Item",
      completed: false,
    };
    setItems([...items, newItem]);
  };
  return (
    <ServerSideProps createItem={createItem}>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item {...item} />
      ))}
    </ServerSideProps>
  );
};

const ListContainer = () => {
  const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);

  const createList = () => {
    const newList = {
      id: Math.random(),
      title: "New List",
      items: [],
    };
    setLists([...lists, newList]);
  };

  return (
    <ServerSideProps createList={createList}>
      {lists.map((list) => (
        <List key={list.id} {...list} />
      ))}
    </ServerSideProps>
  );
};
```

This is only pseudo-code as I can't post huge real-world code.

Now suppose a connected client calls the `toggle` function. This would re-render the `Item` component on the server and send the updated component to the client. This is ok, as there's not much changed data that needs to be sent to the client.

However, suppose you call the `createList` function. This would re-render the `ListContainer` component which keeps all the lists. Re-rendering the component is not costly, but sending the data is. Imagine you have hundreds of lists with hundreds of items.

Sending the whole updated lists array every time a list is created and another item is added to an array seems unneccesary.

Most of the data hasn't changed so I don't need to send it again.

I suppose instead of sending the whole state, I figure out what changed on the server (. e.g. inserting an object into the array), I then generate an action e.g. `{action: 'insert', 'prop': 'lists', data: {...}}`.

On the client side I somehow mutate the GraphQL cache inserting the data at the right place.

You can reproduce the problem in a current app. If you head over to https://lists.state-less.cloud and add a lot of lists each with a lot of items, you can see that adding a list becomes increasingly slow.

It's still working as supposed, but I figure this is a point worth optimizing as the optimization can be done in the framework and everything built with it would benefit from the optimization.

I'm not sure if there's not a better solution. It seems like there are a lot of pitfalls implemting incremental synchronization. What if one request get's lost and the states grow out of sync, then you would need to reload the page.

Are there some practical guides on how to properly implement such a process? I fear that it's a lot of effort and that I may introduce hard to find bugs.

Comment: There are papers written on data synchronization, conflict resolution, etc. and it's complex. *(But almost all apps are easier than games which have additional considerations.)* It'll boil down to how consistent things need to be and when, and how likely collisions with other actors' data are likely to be.

Comment: @DaveNewton sounds like a lot of effort and will likely overcomplicate things. Is there at least an easy way to compute changes based on comparing two arrays? I figure, deletion and insertion from arrays are easy to implement and will solve 90% of my problems

Comment: Sure, array diffs *(assuming comparable)* are solved (and probably in a library).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your solution feels like an overkill, feels like you're recreating `Next.Js` with added complexity, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

I don't understand why you need to store whole react components on server.

I've done synchronized, enterprise grade, react apps in the past and the way I handled it is this:

Shared Global state was stored in-memory on server. This contained only the relevant shared parts of the state. This state was stored in `Redis`.

When website initially loaded that state was fetched and loaded into `Redux`, or other state management solution. This kept the components synchronized.

Every time one of the actions would update Redux state, it would also dispatch a server event. Server would update server state and then propagate the actions to other connected clients.

When connected clients received the event, they would also dispatch local Redux action, that kept the state updated and in-sync.

Why this approach works nice is that on each update you just send relevant action, with relevant data.

EDIT:

Based on your comment I think you should not send the whole state:

Let's imagine that we go with sending whole state.

Given 2 clients that are subscribed A and B. Let's say A clicks a button, which causes state update.
Whole state gets sent to server, server receives it but before it can be received by client B, B also, clicks a different button causing whole different state update to be sent to server.

After this client B receives an update, rewrites whole state and is in completely different state then it was.

Client A also receives an update based on B and overwrites the state. Now client A and B both have different states.

There are ways you could manage this, you would include additional logic in the server to manage this. But, imagine if there are not just 2-3 clients but 50, now updates would be very frequent and it would be very hard to track which state which client is in.

Now let's consider option 2 of only sending actions:

Let's say we have centralized state which is fetched only once, initially and we then update this state based on actions both in server and in clients.

Let's discuss same scenario we discussed above:

So, client A sends an action, server state is updated, local state is also updated.
Client B sends an action before Action A is received, server state is again updated based on action(If they are different actions both action update different parts of state, so information is preserved, if they are same actions, later action is kept, which is probably desirable),

Later B receives an action from A, also updates local state and nothing is overwritten, same goes for A.

This can easily scale to many clients since, it's much easier to manage these actions on server side, for example you could easily check if action A blocks action B. Plus, since users are probably interacting with different parts of the webpage, updates won't interfere with each other.

Comment: It's not meant to be a replacement for next.js. It simply let's you code business logic using components, states and hooks. This could be any serverside application. It's not SSR. You can use it together with next.js, but it's not a replacement.  What you outline is basically what I'm doing. I publish the state und subscribed components receive it. This still has the problem that I send huge amounts of data when the outer component changes. I can either send the whole state over the network or only the change to the state.

Comment: Hey, added an edit, long update so better keep there I think

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really follow your logic. The client doesn't send any updated state to the server. The client simply calls a function on the server which updates serverside state. This causes a component to re-render, and send the updated state of the component to all subscribed clients.  Invoking a function from the client side re-renders the component so any operation is done on the newest state. Because JavaScript is single-threaded, states don't "interfere" with each other. There's also not a single state for the whole server, but many nested components each with many states.

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of the question. Array diffs are solved. You can use the library [fast-array-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-array-diff) which does exactly what you need.

It even provides a `getPatch` method you can use to obtain an array of edit actions which can be sent over to the client and applied to the client side array using the `applyPatch(arrayOld, patchArray)` method.

It works with the following arrays:

```
[
  { type: "remove", oldPos: 0, newPos: 0, items: [1] },
  { type: "add", oldPos: 3, newPos: 2, items: [4] },
];
```

The same principle could be applied to object keys. There's [deep-object-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff) which could be used to compute changes, but it doesn't have a patch functionality, so you would need to implement this on your own.

If array diffs solve 90% of your problem, then fast-array-diff seems like the perfect solution.